# How to add score when changing a sprite from hidden to unhidden

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How do I make it so when a sprite is originally hidden is unhidden when a button is pressed and when something touches that sprite then it adds +1 to the score?

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    location = touches.first!.location(in: self)

    if Top3.contains(location) && Top3.isHidden == true {
        Top3.isHidden = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same line where Top3.isHidden = false you would have to have a variable to your score and just do score = score + 1.

```
  if Top3.contains(location) && Top3.isHidden == true {
        Top3.isHidden = false;
myGlobalScoreVariable = myGlobalScoreVariable + 1 

    }
```

Of course it would not be called "myGoalScoreVariable" but whatever you've set your score variable to be.

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question and you actually mean, how to do it once its been unHidden in which case you would just need another if statement when isHidden == false.

```
if Top3.contains(location) && Top3.isHidden == false {

myGlobalScoreVariable = myGlobalScoreVariable + 1 

    }
```